# Getting Operational Error while submitting data from form in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I want to submit the input (users info) into the users table, but getting operational errors.

```
  from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.messagebox import *
    import sqlite3

def submit():
    connect = sqlite3.connect(r'D:\ACCTGSYSTEM.db')
    c = connect.cursor()
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO users(Fname, Lname, Uname, Pass) VALUES (?,?,?,?,)',(fname.get(),lname.get(),uname.get(),passw.get()))
```

[SCREEN SHOT OF OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyM8V.png)

Comment: I think you might have forgotten the ";"?

Comment: remove the last comma in `(?,?,?,?,)`

Comment: this seems to have nothing to do with tkinter. You should remove that from the code, and remove the tkinter tag.

Comment: Thanks for that but another Error appeared: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 2 supplied.

Comment: @bryan I have a form which uses tkinter

Comment: @amorsiko1987 you have problem with SQL not with tkinter. You could remove all tkinter code and still have the same problem.

Comment: maybe `print(fname.get(),lname.get(),uname.get(),passw.get())` to see what values you have.

Comment: doesn't `executemany` expect `many` sets of data ? and even you have one set of data shouldn't you use list of sets `[ (fname.get(),lname.get(),uname.get(),passw.get()), ]` ? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331894/i-cant-get-pythons-executemany-for-sqlite3-to-work-properly)

Comment: @furas  print(fname.get(),lname.get(),uname.get(),passw.get()). output exact data i have entered on the text box. What I dont understand is why Im getting problem inserting these data into the database

Answer (score 0):

I can't check it.

See word `many` in word `executemany()`.

`executemany("...", data)` expects list with many sets of data like this

```
data = [ 
    (fname1, lname1, uname1, passw1), 
    (fname2, lname2, uname2, passw2), 
    (fname3, lname3, uname3, passw3), 
]
```

If you have one set of data you still have to use list

```
data = [ 
    (fname1, lname1, uname1, passw1), 
]
```

not single set of data

```
data = (fname1, lname1, uname1, passw1)
```

Or use `execute("...", data)` with single set of data

```
data = (fname1, lname1, uname1, passw1)
```

---

see example with `executemany` in doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html