# How can I append a column in sqlite3 and fill its values with pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'd like to append a column into the table existing in sqlite3 database, using values stored in a pandas Series.

My original DataFrame df looks like:

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

And this is stored as a table in sqlite3 also. 
If I add a column to df as:

```
df['c'] = df.a + df.b
```

then df will be:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  3  4  7
```

whereas the table in the sqlite3 db is not changed yet. 
What I want to do is to append a column ('c') into the table in sqlite3 and fill its values with df['c'].

What I tried is:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('data/a.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('alter table temptable add column c integer')
con.commit()
cur.execute('update temptable set c=?', df.c)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

However, it is not working. Is there a possible way to perform bulk update for the new column 'c' in sqlite3? The number of rows is usually around 100,000,000.

Comment: so you have around 100mm row in your database ? then you need to think about use chunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ALTER TABLE worked and you were able to add the new column, try using `sqlite3`'s [executemany](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) method to insert values into the new column. The accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331894) shows you how to do it (Note that you'll need a primary key on your table)

As an alternative, [this link](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-pandas-databases) shows you how to use [DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to update the entire table using the dataframe without writing sql query yourself.